# Is there a difference between LoginAction and FormsAuthentication.SignOut()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I was first using the logout action that was automatically created by the Web Forms project in Visual Studio (I know Web Forms is outdated, but I need it for a legacy piece of code):

```
<asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log out" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
```

So I assume that what makes the user log out is the part `LogoutAction="Redirect"`

But in the tutorial I was looking at, the logout action would be done this way:

```
private void cmdLogout_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Response.Redirect("~/", true);
}
```

Is there a difference between the two, or `LogoutAction="Redirect"` does the same as `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LogoutAction` in combination with `LogoutPageUrl` just tell the `LoginStatus` control how to do the redirect in case the user clicks the logout menu item.

The `LoginStatus` executes that same `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`, followed by a redirect which happens according to the specified settings.

See the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/UI/WebControls/loginstatus.cs,281).

```
private void LogoutClicked(object Source, CommandEventArgs e) 
{        
    // ...

    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    
    switch (LogoutAction) {
        // ...
        
        case LogoutAction.Redirect:
            string url = LogoutPageUrl;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(url)) {
                url = ResolveClientUrl(url);
            }
            else {
                // Use FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl as a fallback
                url = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl;
            }
            Page.Response.Redirect(url, false);
            break;
    }
}
```